# Bind xml file to datagrid in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am working on silverlight to bind a xml file to datagrid.I have found many example but my xml file is very complex. so how to read or bind it to data grid.
Below is my xml file and i want to read element "EntityType" with its sub element and its attribute values.

Thanks.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="1.0">
    <Schema Namespace="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm">
      <EntityType Name="SdkMessageRequestField">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="SdkMessageRequestFieldId" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="FieldMask" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true" />
        <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
      </EntityType>
      <ComplexType Name="EntityReference">
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="true" />
        <Property Name="LogicalName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
        <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
      </ComplexType>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XDocument x = XDocument.Load("XMLFileName.xml");

```
    var a = (from c in x.Descendants("edmx").Elements("Schema").Elements("EntityType/ComplexType") 

             select new 
             { 
                 Name = c.Parent.Attribute("Name"), 
                 PropertyName = c.Attribute("Name"),
                 PropertyType = c.Attribute("Type")
             }).ToArray(); 

    foreach (var itm in a) 
    { 
        // TODO:..... 
    }
```